# WP_Query for multiple post types just shows one

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query

I have an issue, that I do not really understand. I hope, you can help me. I would like to have a WP_query for multiple post types:

```
$query = array(
  'category_name' => $category,
  'post_type' => array('podcast', 'post')
);
$posts = new WP_Query($query);
```

It does just reply my posts, no podcasts.

Dump from `$posts->request` is

```
SELECT   wp_posts.*
            FROM wp_posts
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
            WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (152) 
  AND 
  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (414,432)
) AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'podcast' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-success' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-failed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-schedule' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-draft' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')) OR (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-success' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-failed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-schedule' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-draft' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
            GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
            ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

But...

```
$query = array(
  'category_name' => $category,
  'post_type' => array('podcast')
);
$posts = new WP_Query($query);
```

...does really display the podcasts.

Dump from `$posts->request` is

```
SELECT   wp_posts.*
            FROM wp_posts
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
            WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (414,432)
) AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'podcast' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-success' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-failed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-schedule' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'tribe-ea-draft' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
            GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
            ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

So why doe all podcasts disappear in that query, when I do add 'post' to the array? I thought the array would display posts AND podcasts?

Comment: Try inspecting the SQL query, e.g. add `var_dump( $posts->request );` after the `new WP_Query` call. Do that on both your snippets and share what the dump output.

Comment: do you have `pre_get_posts` filters active? It's very odd to see `-1` wrapped in quotes, and you've also specified `category` but does the podcasts post type support it? Posts have to match _all_ the things you specified, so it won't match posts in that category then ignore it for podcasts

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you! Yes, I added `category` to the `post_type` - and even if I reduce the query to filter only by `post_type` it does not reply with my podcasts, as soon as I add `post` to the array.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you! I've done that and added the dumps above.

Comment: @wepli23 it seemed like there's a plugin/code which is filtering the query args, but (it's probably) not done properly, hence your 1st snippet didn't return the expected results - [see diff here](https://www.diffchecker.com/t3Ys8y5s/) whereby there's an extra term (`152`) in the taxonomy query. `'suppress_filters' => true` can be added to your `$query` array to suppress the filters, but you should instead try to locate the problematic code - try searching for `pre_get_posts` in the active theme, and/or try deactivating plugins and see if the same issue persists.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks again. I already tried to investigate on this, but I didn't find any `pre_get_posts` in `functions.php` - I assume, it really has to be in some plug-in. Unfortunately `'suppress_filters' => true` does not work as well...

Comment: Well, that's weird, but in that case, with your 1st snippet, what's the output of `var_dump( $posts );` ? Have you tried deactivating plugins, and how did it go? And can you edit your post/question and add your post type *registration* code?

Comment: `pre_get_posts` filters could be in your theme, or any of the plugins or code that's being loaded into WordPress, not just `functions.php`, also you're still using `'-1'` not `-1` which is super weird, can you switch it so that the number of posts per page is a number and not a snippet of text containing a number? Where is the code located? How is `$category` being given its value? Can you add the registration code as Sally requested?

Comment: Thank you, I tried to completey remove the `-1` oder `'-1'` - it does not change a thing in my output. The post type `podcast` is set by a plug in, so I don't have a registration code for that. $category is set by `get_queried_object()->slug` - but for testing I also set it manually to a value.

Comment: @SallyCJ  How can I post the whole `var_dump( $posts );`? Is is very long and does contain private data.

Comment: My best guess is that the post type isn't actually 'podcast'.  Can you go to the edit screen for one of the podcasts and copy paste the part of the url in your browser behind `/wp-admin/`

Comment: @TonyDjukic It is `post.php?post=29339&action=edit` - but if it is not type `podcast`, why does the second query `'post_type' => array('podcast')` find my episodes and `'post_type' => array('podcast', 'post')` does not?

Comment: That is weird. I did however give you the wrong instruction, apologies.  What I meant to ask for what the URL of the 'podcasts' list screen.  So the screen that shows you the list of all of the podcast entries you've created.

Comment: Oh, this ist `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=series&post_type=podcast`

Comment: @wepli23 you could use a site such as pastebin.com and just replace the private data with dummy ones. But is the issue still happening? What have you done since your last comment? Have you tried deactivating plugins *other than* the podcast plugin, and did doing so help? Could there be a misconfiguration or unwanted choices etc. in the plugin settings? (try checking the relevant admin UI/screens)

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing is due to how WordPress handles queries with multiple post types. When you specify multiple post types in the `post_type` parameter of a `WP_Query`, WordPress will only return posts that match *all* of the specified post types. In your case, when you include both `'post'` and `'podcast'` in the `post_type` array, WordPress tries to find posts that are of both types, which is likely not what you intend.

If you want to query posts from multiple post types separately, you'll need to create multiple queries or use a custom SQL query to achieve the desired result. Here's an example of how you could modify your code to query posts from both `'post'` and `'podcast'` types separately:

```php
$query_posts = array(
  'category_name' => $category,
  'post_type' => 'post',                      
  'posts_per_page'  => '-1',
  'orderby' => 'date'
);
$posts = new WP_Query($query_posts);

$query_podcasts = array(
  'category_name' => $category,
  'post_type' => 'podcast',                      
  'posts_per_page'  => '-1',
  'orderby' => 'date'
);
$podcasts = new WP_Query($query_podcasts);
```

This way, you'll have two separate queries, one for posts and one for podcasts, and you can loop through the results of each query separately to display the content.

Comment: Thank you, Ali! Okay, then I have to try two querys. But then I have to manage to display the results all together - so merge them and sort them all by date. How can I do that? That would be much easier with just one query... But what I still do not understand: Why does the query show all my posts in my first example `array('podcast', 'post')`- although the posts do not match the podcast type?

Comment: @AliAlizadegan "*WordPress tries to find posts that are of both types*" - a post can only ever have one single post type, and when the `post_type` is an array of post types, WordPress will search for posts where the type is in that array, just like you could see from the `$posts->request` dump in the revised question. I.e. Basically, there's a `(wp_posts.post_type = 'podcast' ...) OR (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' ...)` ( note the `OR` ) in the SQL statement.